# Android Bootstrap Widgets

Tags: android, widget, dropdown

I am working with com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapDropDown and I don't understand how to get the value of the selected item from the dropdown

dropdownresource.xml

```
`<resources>
  <string name="app_name">GTFirstPage</string>
  <string name="navigation_drawer_open">Open navigation drawer</string>
  <string name="navigation_drawer_close">Close navigation drawer</string>
  <string name="action_settings">Settings</string>
  <array name="bootstrap_dropdown_example_data">
    <item>Family Trip</item>
    <item>Camping</item>
    <item>Business Trip</item> 
    <item>{dropdown_separator}</item> 
    <item>Custom Trip</item>
   </array>
</resources>`
```

plan.xml

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
 xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"
 tools:context="com.example.hp.gtfirstpage.plantrip">


<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:id="@+id/autotv1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left|center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:background="#f3f3f3"
        android:hint="Where do you want to go?"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="107dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"

        android:weightSum="1">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="176dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:text="Destination"
            android:textSize="30sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:background="#f3f3f3"
            android:ems="10"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:text="" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="107dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView11"
            android:layout_width="176dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.00"
            android:text="Category"
            android:textSize="30sp"/>

        <com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapDropDown

            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
            app:bootstrapBrand="regular"
            app:bootstrapExpandDirection="down"
            app:bootstrapSize="md"
            app:bootstrapText="Select Category"
            app:dropdownResource="@array/bootstrap_dropdown_example_data"
            app:roundedCorners="true" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="107dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView13"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="Date"
            android:textSize="30sp" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="85dp"

            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv4"
                android:layout_width="165dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:background="#f3f3f3"
                android:inputType="date" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView14"
                android:layout_width="45dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="to"
                android:textSize="30sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tv5"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:ems="10"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:background="#f3f3f3"
                android:inputType="date" />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="107dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt1"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="BACK" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bt2"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="DONE" />

    </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

   </FrameLayout>
```

plantrip.java

```
 package com.example.hp.gtfirstpage;
 import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
 import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
 import android.widget.TextView;
 import android.widget.Toast;
 import com.beardedhen.androidbootstrap.BootstrapDropDown;

 public class plantrip extends Fragment implements  
  AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener 
 {    
   BootstrapDropDown spin;
   String city,category,dest;
   @Override
   public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      View root=null;
      root= inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_plantrip, container, false);

      spin = (BootstrapDropDown) root.findViewById(R.id.spinner);

      spin.setOnDropDownItemClickListener(new 
      BootstrapDropDown.OnDropDownItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(ViewGroup parent, View v, int id) {
         //   category=spin.getResources().getResourceName(spin.getId()); 
        }
      });

    return root;
   }
 }
```

I am new to android so if there is any mistake please explain properly.
Please tell me how to retrieve items from dropdown list.
Thank You!!!

Comment: Ty this String text = spin.getSelectedItem().toString();

Answer (score 1):

BootstrapDropDown has a method called getDropdownData(); 
This method returns a String[] array containing the items in your BootstapDropDown. Use int id as an index for your array.  The 'int id' gets passed to you as a parameter of the method:

public void onItemClick(ViewGroup parent, View v, **int id**) {...}

I believe you can grab the selected item by adding this line to your code:

String[] dropDownItems = spin.getDropdownData();
String item = dropDownItems[id];

```
 spin.setOnDropDownItemClickListener(new 
  BootstrapDropDown.OnDropDownItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(ViewGroup parent, View v, int id) {
     //   category=spin.getResources().getResourceName(spin.getId()); 
          String[] dropDownItems = spin.getDropdownData();
          String item = dropDownItems[id];
    }
  });
```

// made a couple of edits to fix a mistake

// I hope this helped!